# Apache 301 redirect with get parameters

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, lightspeed

I am trying to do a 301 redirect with lightspeed webserver htaccess with no luck.

I need to do a url to url redirect without any related parameters.

for example:

from: `http://www.example.com/?cat=123`

to: `http://www.example.com/some_url`

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/?cat=123 http://www.example.com/some_url/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to post your code inline in the question. Without that we won't be able to help you. So what _are_ the rules you did try "with no luck"?

Comment: I have added the code I tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding your code to your question. Once more we see how important that is:

your issue is that a `RewriteRule` does *not* operate on URLs, but on paths. So you need something like that instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /some_url/ [R=301,L,NC,QSD]
```

From your question it is not clear if you want to ignore any GET parameters or if you only want to redirect if certain parameters are set. So here is a variant that will only get applied if some parameter is actually set in the request:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)cat=123(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /some_url/ [R=301,L,NC,QSD]
```

Another thing that does not really get clear is if you want all URLs below `http://www.example.com/` (so below the path `/`) to be rewritten, or only that exact URL. If you want to keep any potential further path component of a request and still rewrite (for example `http://www.example.com/foo => http://www.example.com/some_url/foo`), then you need to add a capture in your regular expression and reuse the captured path components:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /some_url/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSD]
```

For either of this to work you need to have the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files enabled by means of the `AllowOverride` command. See the official documentation of the rewriting module for details. And you have to take care that that `-htaccess` style file is actually readable by the http server process and that it is located right inside the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder in the local file system.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I think that `[^|&]cat=123[&|$]` should be `(?:^|&)cat=123(?:&|$)` and a `?` (or `QSD` flag for Apache >= 2.4) is missing at the end of the destination to actually remove the original query string (Apache will copy the old one here).

Comment: @julp Thanks for the hints!